# How to get iota out of an address that has already been used twice?

Tags: security, address, address-reuse, winternitz

Is it possible to get IOTAs safely out of an address from which two or more transactions were made already? With safely I mean that there is no chance to get hacked if the third or later transaction is unconfirmed for a long time or invalid.

I have read about the Winternitz hash and the other threads about not making more than one transaction from one source address but I have not found a solution how to circumvent the problem if some funds are still stuck at the source address.

This thread does not provide a solution to the problem: [What happens if I receive IOTAs at an address I've already spent from?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/244/what-happens-if-i-receive-iotas-at-an-address-ive-already-spent-from)

Comment: This question is quite similar https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/380/does-every-pending-transaction-pose-a-threat-for-my-remaining-funds-in-the-walle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it is not possible to reuse an IOTA address without revealing a part of it's [private key](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/584/10).**

If you own an address, from which you have already spent once, the only solution is to do [this](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/269/10).

To see why it's not possible to sign more than once without revealing your private key, you could take a look at these:

- [What information is leaked if I reuse an address?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/245/10)
- [Why are the 50% I reveal when signing random?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/467/10)

Answer (score 1):

> How to get iota out of an address that has already been used twice?

use the CLI wallet https://github.com/iotaledger/cli-app to avoid the "key reuse" error

> Is it possible to get IOTAs safely out of an address from which two or more transactions were made already?

If you spent some funds from an address, the address is already not safe to keep anymore IOTA in it. Concerning about vulnerability of spending twice put does not matter since you have already exposed some part of your private key by transferring IOTA from the address.